# Parse Cloud Code not executing when called from IOS (works when called using rest api)

Tags: ios, parse-server

I am using Parse Server with both a Website and iOS app. Parse server is hosted on AWS.

I have a simple Cloud function that works when called using the rest api from the website. When i call the same function from my IOS app, the code is not executed

Here is the Cloud Code

```
Parse.Cloud.define("cloud_testServer", function(request, response) {
    console.log(request.user);
    response.success("Connected");   
   return
});
```

I can see this code has been executed in my node.js log on AWS and see the response in my calling app

From IOS, i call

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"cloud_testServer"
       withParameters:@{@"event":self.currentEvent,@"eventInvite": selInvite }
                           block:^(NSObject * result, NSError *error){
                                  NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                  if (!error) {
                                     NSLog(@"%@", result);
                                  }
                       }];
```

There is nothing in the node.js log on AWS and the response and error block in the app are nil

This is the first time i have tried to call cloud code from my IOS app. Usual parse queries work fine from both the website and IOS app.

Any suggestions as to where to look for the problem ?

Comment: It's probably because of the parameters you're sending. `currentEvent` and `selInvite` are both parse objects, then you should probably just send their objectIds instead and then fetch the objects on the server side

Comment: Second. I think it doesn't work if you pass anything that is nil, too. So make sure there are values present. Additionally, have you set a break point at the PFCloud line to ensure that it is actually getting hit?